# How to set time to midnight for current day?

Tags: c#, .net

Every time that I create a non-nullable datetime in my mvc3 application it defaults to now(), where now is current date with current time.  I would like to default it to today's date with 12am as the time.

I'm trying to default the time in my mvc...but...the following isn't setting to todays date @12am.  Instead it defaults to now with current date and time.

```
private DateTime _Begin = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 12, 0, 0);
public DateTime Begin { get { return _Begin; } set { _Begin = value; } }
```

How can I set to 12am for the current date for non-nullable datetime?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can use the `Date` property of the DateTime object - eg

```
DateTime midnight = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

So your code example becomes

```
private DateTime _Begin = DateTime.Now.Date;
public DateTime Begin { get { return _Begin; } set { _Begin = value; } }
```

PS. going back to your original code setting the hours to **12** will give you time of *noon* for the current day, so instead you could have used **0**...

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: There is also `DateTime.Today`

Comment: @Erv Indeed if you reflect (disassemble the M$ dll) you'll find `Today` is simply a wrapper for `DateTime.Now.Date` - so personally I find this just shows a little more intent in my code...

Comment: I disagree. Today implies exactly what it says. I never assume time when talking about a day . Having to say Now.Date is overly verbose.

Comment: It made me chuckle to think `Now.Date` is *overly* verbose for an extra 3 characters...

Comment: About the last line: **Never** use many calls to the `Now` property getter in the same expression. `Now` changes! If the code runs near a time where `Day` (and possibly `Month` and `Year`) changes, it will give a wrong output. Like the first of the `Now`-s could be "Nov. 30th, 23:59:59.9999...", and the last one could be "Dec. 1st, 00:00:00.0000...". Your result could then be **November 1st**, way off.

Answer (score 52):

I believe you are looking for `DateTime.Today`. The documentation states:

> An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to 00:00:00.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx

Your code would be

```
DateTime _Begin = DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: it's not the answer but it helps me :-)

Comment: @vNext Yes it is, it answers the question exactly and is the most concise answer.

Answer (score 9):

Using some of the above recommendations, the following function and code is working for search a date range:

**Set date with the time component set to 00:00:00**

```
public static DateTime GetDateZeroTime(DateTime date)
{
    return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var modifieddatebegin = Tools.Utilities.GetDateZeroTime(form.modifieddatebegin);

var modifieddateend = Tools.Utilities.GetDateZeroTime(form.modifieddateend.AddDays(1));
```

Comment: Your GetDateZeroTime implementation is equivalent to accessing the Date property of the DateTime object, i.e.
date.Date

Answer (score 6):

Only need to set it to

`DateTime.Now.Date`

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
Console.Read();
```

It shows

> "2017-04-08 00:00:00"

on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Related, so I thought I would post for others.  If you want to find the UTC of the start of today (for your timezone) the following code works for any UTC offset (-23.5 thru +23.5).  This looks like we add X hours then subtract X hours, but the important thing is the ".Date" after the add.

```
double utcOffset= 10.0;  // Set to your UTC offset in hours (eg. Melbourne Australia)
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

var startOfToday = now.AddHours(utcOffset - 24.0).Date;
startOfToday = startOfToday.AddHours(24.0 - utcOffset);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the suggested solutions can cause a 1 day error depending on the time associated with each date.  If you are looking for an integer number of calendar days between to dates, regardless of the time associated with each date, I have found that this works well:

```
return (dateOne.Value.Date - dateTwo.Value.Date).Days;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DateTime Date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-DateTime.Now.Hour).AddMinutes(-DateTime.Now.Minute)
   .AddSeconds(-DateTime.Now.Second);
```

Output will be like:

> 07/29/2015 00:00:00

Comment: This question already has a well-received and accepted answer. Please read it and its comments - they explain why your approach is really not a good idea.