# Default timespan for midnight

Tags: c#

I'm trying to calculate the timespan from any time of the day till midnight. My attempt is below, but I don't want to make it short for one second. Is there any default value or a better way?

```
TimeSpan sinceMidnight = TimeSpan.Parse("23:59:59") - TimeSpan.Parse("21:48:42");

Console.WriteLine(sinceMidnight);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set time to midnight for current day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467230/how-to-set-time-to-midnight-for-current-day)

Comment: Then why not `TimeSpan.Parse("24:00:00")` ? It might be easier if you were working with `DateTime` though.

Comment: You could use `TimeSpan.FromHours(24)`. It has also better performance because no string parsing is necessary.

Comment: A TimeSpan represents a duration, not a specific time. There's no midnight. Effectively you're asking the difference between a time and `24 hours`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use string parsing at all? You can also generate the timespans from numbers:

```
TimeSpan sinceMidnight = TimeSpan.FromHours(24) - new TimeSpan(21, 48, 42);
```

String parsing has two disadvantages: It is slow (but it is quite probable you won't notice it because the difference in performance can be neglected). And if you have some typos in your string and it will have the wrong format you won't realize during compile time. This might result in exceptions.